# get selected item from kendo treeview in javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, treeview

I'm trying to get the selected item with a specific id from outside of the kendo treeview.  Basically, I'm writing a js function to try to find out which node is selected.  Is there a way to find out which node (and it's datasource properties) can be extracted?

I can get the node data if the an event listener passes the event but can't figure out a way to get to that node without the event listener.

Once I get that data, I would like to update some button links to go to the next item in the node.

```
//get node WITH listener:
function getNode(e){
    var nodedata = $('#treeName').getKendoTreeView().dataItem(e.node).id;
    console.log(nodedata);
}

//BUT I want to find out from outside of Kendo treeview with something like this:
function getNode() {
    var getSelectedId = $('#treeName').getKendoTreeView().getCurrentSelectedItem().id
    console.log(getSelectedId);
}
```

Comment: [`select()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/methods/select): *Gets or sets the selected node.*.. so, just use `select()` to get the selected item(`li`).

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward. Just use

```
$('#treeName').data("kendoTreeView").select().data().id
```